# how to create button with an icon?

Tags: java, android

I'm  creating a app which contains many button, Each button's background is different. I have created button background from Photoshop. Now  my question is what should be the size of background. I have kept my button height and width as wrap content. When i use android:background:"@drawable/background_img" (image size 30X30), the buttons look like broken (like blurry). What is the best size for background which suits for all screen.

Comment: what is required as a background, just a color or an scenic image ?

Comment: An image. For Example if button implies home, home image is used.

Comment: In my opinion you should prefer using high resolution images, and keeping the size fixed, what layout container are you using : ConstraintLayout or something else (in .xml) also see if ImageButton helps you !

Comment: Should i use bigger size image or lower (30x30 or 150x150)?

Comment: `What is the best size for background which suits for all screen.` Actually, **none**. You should provide an image for each supported screen density and/or resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ImageButton set width and height as you like and then set `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. Try to use bigger image input than 30x30 (its to small), try 96x96 and then try to fit it to height and width you want.

A few days ago i had the same problem, when i gave 32x32 images were blurry, but when I try 64x64 or 96x96 (dont't remember) and `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` it looks so much better.

Comment: It's possible to give these property to normal button with image as background?